# Why excludes the transaction bodies in the structure of the block?

Tags: cryptonote

According to cryptonote standard #3, a block consists of three parts:

```
  - block header,

  - base transaction body,

  - list of transaction identifiers.
```

1. **Why excludes the transaction bodies in the structure of the block?**
2. **What is the structure of the blockchain? Does it include every
   transaction body?**

Comment: Well,interesting. So there maybe a central database to store the transactions in Monero. But how does the verification of each transaction? Same as bitcoin?

Comment: It is distributed, same as Bitcoin, and verification is done in a similar way to Bitcoin, though the details of course vary. This answer should be moved to a comment by someone with that ability.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2049)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blockchain is a logical concept. When you store the blockchain locally, your Monero node implementation can store blocks and transactions together, or in separate places. How your Monero node implementation stores things is only a performance consideration.

There is no need for blocks to always be stored alongside the transactions they logically 'contain'. By using transaction identifiers, it makes it easy for blocks and transactions to be stored in different places for performance reasons, should an implementation choose to do so.